# Issue about mapping MAC address to Ipv6 address

Tags: networking, ipv6

I know that the address in ipv6 with prefix range 001 to 111 should use a 64-bit interface identifier that follows the EUI-64 format, which translates the MAC to ipv6 as below.

```
MAC:00-02-b3-1e-83-29 --> 02-02-b3-ff-fe-1e-83-29 --->ipv6 addr: fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329
```

Then I checked my network status with ipconfig /all on my windows XP, but it seems my ipv6 address doesn't follow the above rule:

```
MAC:00-24-81-XX-XX-XX 
ipv6 addr:2001:da8:8006:225:0:24:81XX:XXXX
```

Obviously it doesn't follow the EUI-64 format. Instead it just directly use the MAC as the last 8 bytes.

Anyone know the reason? Pls Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How was the address obtained? Run `netsh inter ipv6 show addr lev=verb` and look at *Suffix Origin* property of the address. Does it show "Link-Layer Address" or "Manual"?

Comment: It's manual. Thanks. So "Link-Layer Address" means using the EUI-64 format while "manual" means the address is arbitrary?

Comment: Yes. "Manual" means the address was configured by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Copying from my comments)*

Run

```
netsh interface ipv6 show address level=verbose
```

and look at **Suffix Origin** property of the address. EUI-64-based addresses will be labelled as "Link-Layer Address". If it says "Manual", then the address was configured by the user (by `netsh interface ipv6 add address` or `ipv6 adu`), or maybe by a DHCPv6 client if such is running (I don't know how they interface with the IPv6 stack).